# Marinating venison?

Tags: marinade, venison

I have tried again and again to find a good solution to marinating venison as it never turns out right because of the natural jucies. So what is the correct process of doing this or what should i use?

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful here - I can't think of anything special about venison in particular that would make it difficult to marinate. What specifically have you tried and how has it failed to meet your expectations?

Comment: Could it be the cooking process and not the marinade? Venison is very lean and tricky to cook. What is it that you don't like in the final outcome?

Comment: @jasonwhipple Definitely could be the process; what i dont like is no matter what I use it always turns out really gamie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part you have to re-train your mind when eating any wild animal. It will never taste like grain fed cattle. They are wild animals and eat wild things.  Other things that could affect the taste is the processing of the deer. If not bled out very well before  butchering it could have a stronger taste to it. Also, the age of the deer can be a factor. Older deer tend to have a stronger taste.

Some things you could try are soaking it in a brine base marinade for several days in the refrigerator to let the blood escape. You can add fruit juices to this brine as well. Once you do this the silver "skin" on the muscles will become more obvious and easier to remove. Removing that skin could help a lot and make the meat more tender.

Another option is to soak it for at least 1 day in milk and seasonings. Buttermilk, low fat yogurts (even fruit flavored), or ranch dressing is also used by some people.

Lastly, always cook as slow as possible. Roasts should be done at about 275 and steaks should cook as slowly as you can. Cooking to quickly may not give the meat enough time to "bleed out" but then again, it's a balancing act because if to much of the juice comes out you're stuck with a piece of meat that is very dry.

Experimentation is the only way to perfect it for your tastes. Hope this gives you a few new idea's to try out.

Answer (score 1):

As one who has harvested a fair number of deer over the years, I have determined that in order to lessen the "gaminess" taste of venison, marinating it no longer than overnight in a solution of wine (any cheap version will work) and a small amount of fruit juice like lime, lemon or even oranges, works. Just don't add too much and thin out the wine with some water unless you *like* meat with a heavy wine taste (I don't, personally).

The key is to not let the meat marinate *too* long otherwise the flesh becomes quite soft and/or mushy, taking away from the cut steak or roast consistency.

I've found that 6-8 hours is what I prefer but, again, YMMV depending on your preference.

The acidity of the wine and fruit juices work to break down the tougher fibers of the meat, but as mentioned, going too long will be counterproductive.

Also, having some of the taste of the actual venison remaining is why I enjoy the meat. After all you aren't desiring the same taste and texture of beef, are you, since that is the whole purpose of cooking venison?

Lastly, I don't have a specific recipe that I use. It all depends on what my taste buds are looking forward to and knowing how various spices and marinades interact with the meat and that comes from decades of experimentation and personal preferences.